# Error 0x80072ee7 while Installing Nokia recovery. What is it?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, update

Getting this error while installing Nokia Software Recovery v1.5.0

[image]

Log File below :

```
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:55]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\Ajinkya\Downloads\NokiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe, cmdline: ''
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:55]i000: Initializing string variable 'LaunchTarget' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Nokia\Nokia Software Recovery Tool\NokiaSoftwareRecoveryTool.exe'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\Downloads\NokiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.1)' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Nokia Software Recovery Tool 1.5.0'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i100: Detect begin, 48 packages
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK45' to value '378389'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting numeric variable 'VC2005RedistInstalled' to value 1
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'VC2010RedistInstalled' to value '1'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Setting string variable 'VC2012RedistInstalled' to value '1'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Runtimes\x86'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK45 >= 378389' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition 'VC2005RedistInstalled' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition 'VC2010RedistInstalled=1 or VC2010RedistInstalled64=1' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition 'VC2012RedistInstalled=1 or VC2012RedistInstalled64=1' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i103: Detected related package: {6D453000-EF37-43A9-A656-E8311269AB92}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: CheckFreeDiskSpace, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NetFx45Web, state: Present, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: VC2005Redist, state: Present, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: VC2010Redist, state: Present, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: VC2012Redist, state: Present, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: CommunicationLayerCleaner, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: WinUsbCoInstallers, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: WinUsbCompatIdInstaller, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: WinUsbDriversExt, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: EmergencyDownloadDriver, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: USBSerialPortDriver, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NCCD, state: Present, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: Fuse, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: FUP, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: ADUService, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_enUS, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_arSA, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_csCZ, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_daDK, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_deDE, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_elGR, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_esES, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_etEE, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_fiFI, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_frFR, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_ltLT, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_lvLV, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_nbNO, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_nlNL, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_plPL, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_ptBR, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_roRO, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_ruRU, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_skSK, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_slSI, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_svSE, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_thTH, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_trTR, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_zhCN, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_zhHK, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: NSRT_zhTW, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i101: Detected package: PAPI, state: Absent, cached: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i052: Condition 'Privileged <> 0' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:06:58]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0DF0:0634][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 0
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i200: Plan begin, 48 packages, action: Install
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CheckFreeDiskSpace' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_0_CheckFreeDiskSpace.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: NetFx45Web
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VC2005Redist
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VC2010Redist
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VC2012Redist
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: CommunicationLayerCleaner
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_CommunicationLayerCleaner' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_1_CommunicationLayerCleaner.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_WinUsbCoInstallers' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_2_WinUsbCoInstallers.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_WinUsbCompatIdInstaller' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_3_WinUsbCompatIdInstaller.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_WinUsbDriversExt' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_4_WinUsbDriversExt.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_EmergencyDownloadDriver' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_5_EmergencyDownloadDriver.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_USBSerialPortDriver' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_6_USBSerialPortDriver.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Fuse' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_7_Fuse_rollback.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Fuse' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_7_Fuse.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_FUP' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_8_FUP_rollback.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_FUP' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_8_FUP.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: ADUService
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_ADUService' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_9_ADUService.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_ADUService' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_9_ADUService_rollback.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'NOT ( UserLanguageID=1025 OR UserLanguageID=5121 OR UserLanguageID=15361 OR UserLanguageID=3073 OR UserLanguageID=2049 OR UserLanguageID=11265 OR UserLanguageID=13313 OR UserLanguageID=12289 OR UserLanguageID=4097 OR UserLanguageID=6145 OR UserLanguageID=8193 OR UserLanguageID=16385 OR UserLanguageID=10241 OR UserLanguageID=7169 OR UserLanguageID=14337 OR UserLanguageID=9217 OR UserLanguageID=1029 OR UserLanguageID=1030 OR UserLanguageID=1031 OR UserLanguageID=3079 OR UserLanguageID=5127 OR UserLanguageID=4103 OR UserLanguageID=2055 OR UserLanguageID=1032 OR UserLanguageID=3082 OR UserLanguageID=1034 OR UserLanguageID=11274 OR UserLanguageID=16394 OR UserLanguageID=13322 OR UserLanguageID=9226 OR UserLanguageID=5130 OR UserLanguageID=7178 OR UserLanguageID=12298 OR UserLanguageID=17418 OR UserLanguageID=4106 OR UserLanguageID=18442 OR UserLanguageID=22538 OR UserLanguageID=2058 OR UserLanguageID=19466 OR UserLanguageID=6154 OR UserLanguageID=15370 OR UserLanguageID=10250 OR UserLanguageID=20490 OR UserLanguageID=21514 OR UserLanguageID=14346 OR UserLanguageID=8202 OR UserLanguageID=1061 OR UserLanguageID=1035 OR UserLanguageID=1036 OR UserLanguageID=2060 OR UserLanguageID=11276 OR UserLanguageID=3084 OR UserLanguageID=9228 OR UserLanguageID=12300 OR UserLanguageID=15372 OR UserLanguageID=5132 OR UserLanguageID=13324 OR UserLanguageID=6156 OR UserLanguageID=14348 OR UserLanguageID=58380 OR UserLanguageID=8204 OR UserLanguageID=10252 OR UserLanguageID=4108 OR UserLanguageID=7180 OR UserLanguageID=1037 OR UserLanguageID=1050 OR UserLanguageID=1038 OR UserLanguageID=1040 OR UserLanguageID=2064 OR UserLanguageID=1041 OR UserLanguageID=1042 OR UserLanguageID=1063 OR UserLanguageID=1062 OR UserLanguageID=1044 OR UserLanguageID=2068 OR UserLanguageID=1043 OR UserLanguageID=2067 OR UserLanguageID=1045 OR UserLanguageID=1046 OR UserLanguageID=2070 OR UserLanguageID=1048 OR UserLanguageID=2072 OR UserLanguageID=1049 OR UserLanguageID=2073 OR UserLanguageID=1051 OR UserLanguageID=1060 OR UserLanguageID=1053 OR UserLanguageID=2077 OR UserLanguageID=1054 OR UserLanguageID=1055 OR UserLanguageID=2052 OR UserLanguageID=4100 OR UserLanguageID=5124 OR UserLanguageID=3076 OR UserLanguageID=1028 )' evaluates to true.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_NSRT_enUS' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_10_NSRT_enUS_rollback.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_NSRT_enUS' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_10_NSRT_enUS.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1025 OR UserLanguageID=5121 OR UserLanguageID=15361 OR UserLanguageID=3073 OR UserLanguageID=2049 OR UserLanguageID=11265 OR UserLanguageID=13313 OR UserLanguageID=12289 OR UserLanguageID=4097 OR UserLanguageID=6145 OR UserLanguageID=8193 OR UserLanguageID=16385 OR UserLanguageID=10241 OR UserLanguageID=7169 OR UserLanguageID=14337 OR UserLanguageID=9217' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1029' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1030' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1031 OR UserLanguageID=3079 OR UserLanguageID=5127 OR UserLanguageID=4103 OR UserLanguageID=2055' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1032' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=3082 OR UserLanguageID=1034 OR UserLanguageID=11274 OR UserLanguageID=16394 OR UserLanguageID=13322 OR UserLanguageID=9226 OR UserLanguageID=5130 OR UserLanguageID=7178 OR UserLanguageID=12298 OR UserLanguageID=17418 OR UserLanguageID=4106 OR UserLanguageID=18442 OR UserLanguageID=22538 OR UserLanguageID=2058 OR UserLanguageID=19466 OR UserLanguageID=6154 OR UserLanguageID=15370 OR UserLanguageID=10250 OR UserLanguageID=20490 OR UserLanguageID=21514 OR UserLanguageID=14346 OR UserLanguageID=8202' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1061' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1055' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=2052 OR UserLanguageID=4100 OR UserLanguageID=5124' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=3076' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i052: Condition 'UserLanguageID=1028' evaluates to false.
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_PAPI' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_11_PAPI_rollback.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_PAPI' to value 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_1.5.0_20140906180658_11_PAPI.log'
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: CheckFreeDiskSpace, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: WinUsbCoInstallers, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: WinUsbCompatIdInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: WinUsbDriversExt, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: EmergencyDownloadDriver, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: USBSerialPortDriver, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: NCCD, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: Fuse, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: FUP, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: ADUService, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: NSRT_enUS, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: NSRT_arSA, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: NSRT_trTR, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: NSRT_zhCN, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i201: Planned package: PAPI, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:20]i300: Apply begin
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:26]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:57]i361: Created a system restore point.
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:57]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\.be\Bootstrapper.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\Bootstrapper.exe'
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:57]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}, version: 1.5.0.0
[078C:1054][2014-09-06T18:07:58]i305: Verified acquired payload: CheckFreeDiskSpace at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\CheckFreeDiskSpace, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E893B08-5155-4C03-A80C-7D9E96FFDDD2}v1.00.0000\CheckFreeDiskSpace.msi.
[078C:1054][2014-09-06T18:07:58]i305: Verified acquired payload: CommunicationLayerCleaner at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\CommunicationLayerCleaner, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\66803FA721B5BDD0FD7793C405C83FF635DDAF6D\CommLayerCleaner.exe.
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:58]w343: Prompt for source of package: WinUsbCoInstallers, payload: WinUsbCoInstallers, path: C:\Users\Ajinkya\Downloads\WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:58]i338: Acquiring package: WinUsbCoInstallers, payload: WinUsbCoInstallers, download from: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Unknown HTTP status code 0, returned from URL: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to connect to URL: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to get size and time for URL: http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi' to: 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\WinUsbCoInstallers'
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to acquire payload from: 'http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/WinUsbCoInstallers/1.1.8.1406/WinUsbCoInstallers.msi' to working path: 'C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\WinUsbCoInstallers'
[0DF0:1114][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e313: Failed to acquire payload: WinUsbCoInstallers to working path: C:\Users\Ajinkya\AppData\Local\Temp\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\WinUsbCoInstallers, error: 0x80072ee7.
[078C:1054][2014-09-06T18:07:59]i351: Removing cached package: CommunicationLayerCleaner, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\66803FA721B5BDD0FD7793C405C83FF635DDAF6D\
[078C:1054][2014-09-06T18:07:59]i351: Removing cached package: CheckFreeDiskSpace, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E893B08-5155-4C03-A80C-7D9E96FFDDD2}v1.00.0000\
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:59]e000: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:59]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}
[078C:1670][2014-09-06T18:07:59]i352: Removing cached bundle: {c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c19d81de-9c3e-4550-ac22-38a0575397ee}\
[0DF0:0F24][2014-09-06T18:07:59]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80072ee7, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: Looks like it's having trouble downloading the additional installers (for USB drivers and such). Check your internet connectivity (specifically to see if you can connect to http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com) and then try again.